# Error al llamar servicio web (asmx)

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, .asmx

Estoy creando clase que sera la estructura que siempre me va devolver todos lo servicios (llamadas asíncronas)

```
public class RespuestaServicio
{
public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
public string Error { get; set; }
public int Codigo { get; set; }
public string Excepcion { get; set; }
public Object Resulto { get; set; }
}
```

Se supone que la variable **Resulto** debe tener la información que debe devolver dicho método del sevicio(List, string, bool, Object etc)

Cuando llamo el servicio  y  la variable resultado es un List por ejemplo da este error

> Error al generar el documento XML. ---> No se puede utilizar en este contexto el tipo System.Collections.Generic.List`

Intente con un array y tampoco, cuando es un string o bool no da problema  no se si se puede hacer esto.

Como podría resolver esto? o que alternativa podría usar para retorno tanto el dato como el objecto de error **sin usar variable por referencia**?

**NOTA**: En el cliente al llamar servicio lo encerre en otro metodo que usa async y await, por lo cual no puede usar parametros por referencia

Hay algo que no especifique y creo que algunos de los que me responde se confundieron.

La clase RespuestaServicio es una clase en webservice,  es donde almaceno la respuesta para enviar al cliente.  y cuando en la respuesta asigno una lista da error

Answer (score 1):

Podrias crear una clase Resulto, por ejemplo:

```
Public class Resulto{ 
List nombreLista { get; set; } 
string nombreString { get; set; } 
bool nombreBool { get; set; }
Object nombreObject { get; set; }
}
```

Y en tu modelo llamado RespuestaServicio seria algo así:

```
public class RespuestaServicio
{
public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
public string Error { get; set; }
public int Codigo { get; set; }
public string Excepcion { get; set; }
public Resulto resulto { get; set; }
}
```

Y ya nada mas vas llamando el retorno que tu necesites, dependiendo del tipo de dato que sea.

Tal vez no te entendí muy bien y eso no es lo que buscas, pero espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: Creo que lo que tu sugieres es que cree una nueva clase "Resultado" con los tipo de dato posibles de la respuesta y que esa clase tenga referencia desde la otra "RespuestaServicio"  y en cliente en base a que funcion llame obtener la informacion?

Comment: Así es, y en el momento del llamado podrías devolver el tipo de dato que requieras y evitarías esos problemas. Espero y te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Si es una opción,  pero no quiero optar por es, porque no son datos nativos, también hay devoluciones de varias clases,  y quisiera algo mas limpio a implementar, pero gracias tu sugerencia ;)

Answer (score 0):

La solución que conseguí fue la siguiente:

Cambiar:

```
public Object Resulto { get; set; }
```

a

```
public List<Object> Resulto { get; set; }
```

También edite los métodos que devolvían valores no lista (string,bool etc) para que lo hicieran y asi indiferentemente el tipo de dato que devuleva en esa variable "Resulto" no me da problema para consumirla en el cliente

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que controlar la [Serialización de SOAP y XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/90c86ass(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Servicio:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Resultado
    {
        [XmlElement(Type = typeof(Mascota), ElementName = "Mascota")]
        [XmlElement(Type = typeof(List<Persona>), ElementName = "Personas")]
        [XmlElement(Type = typeof(string), ElementName = "string")]
        public object Respuesta { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Persona
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Mascota
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class WebService1 : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public Resultado RespuestaCadena()
        {
            return new Resultado { Respuesta = "Hola Mundo" };
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public Resultado RespuestaMascota()
        {
            return new Resultado { Respuesta = new Mascota { Nombre = "Tobi" } };
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public Resultado DinamicoListaPersona()
        {
            return new Resultado { Respuesta = new List<Persona> { new Persona { Nombre = "David" } } };
        }
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

Al obtener `Resultado` como objeto Mascota

```
<Resultado xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Mascota>
<Nombre>Tobi</Nombre>
</Mascota>
</Resultado>
```

Al obtener `Resultado` como objeto String

```
<Resultado xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<string>Hola Mundo</string>
</Resultado>
```

Al obtener `Resultado` como objeto un arreglo de tipo Persona

```
<Resultado xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Personas>
<Persona>
<Nombre>David</Nombre>
</Persona>
</Personas>
</Resultado>
```

Comment: Hola,  no estoy seguro si entiendo tu sugerencia,  aclaro un poco mas la idea,  yo tengo funciones que devuelve objectos tipo persona, otro que devuelve un tipo carro, List de carros, que devuelve string,bool etc

La razón que declaro "Resultado" como object es por eso, no que tipo de variable voy a retorrnar.

Si le coloco esa decoracion al atributo, no lo estaria atando a una clase en especial?

Comment: @joseantonioariasrodriguez ¿Que **"estándar"** de servicio estás implementando?

Comment: Asmx en .net,  si te refiere a respuesta del servicio, todos devuelven un objecto tipo "RespuestaServicio"  que tiene atributos como por ejemplo "IsSuccess" para saber si todo fue correcto, "error" para saber que error ocurrio en el llamado etc.

El atributo tipo Object "Resultado" es donde viene la informacion solicitada,  por ejemplo  si llamo a un servicio para obtener un listado de persona; en ese variable estara el List<Personas> que me da el servicio,  si el servicio me tiene que decir solo true o false para saber si algo se ejecuto, entonces me viene en la variable "Resultado"

Comment: ¿-1? No entender... @joseantonioariasrodriguez, te entiendo perfectamente. Quieres obtener un resultado **genérico**. Si estás trabajando con SOAP, el intercambio de información es a través de XML. Por tal motivo se tiene que serializar una clase para obtener como resultado. Alternativas con `ASMX`, usar `JSON` para la devolución de datos y convertir al tipo que tu definas.

Comment: @joseantonioariasrodriguez Por si acaso, ¿Probaste si mi respuesta te funcionó? usando como prueba dos tipos diferentes.

Comment: No, no la probé, porque no entendí que reemplazar por "MiClase" porque no puedo definir una clase ahi porque lo mismo que te comento de que es genérica la respuesta.

Comment: @joseantonioariasrodriguez actualicé mi código para una mejor comprensión.

Comment: Gracias por su colaboración, ya entiendo bien a que te refieres, ya aplique una solución que fue la que indique, pero voy a probar la que me indicas, a ver si consumiendo el servicio no me el error que antes.

Antes me gustario que me comentaras lo siguiente,  eso quiere decir que por cada tipo de dato que sea posible devolver por alguna de las funciones del servicio, debe estar especificado en decorado de la variable?  o hay  alguna otra manera?

Comment: @joseantonioariasrodriguez en mi rato libre voy a probar con [`TypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) para editar los atributos.

Comment: No era exactamente lo que necesitaba, pero lo que dices funciona de la manera que tu lo indicas